# What is an alternative to <!! in cljs?

Tags: asynchronous, clojurescript

a go block returns a channel and not the return value, so how can one extract the return value in a go block, when cljs doesn't have `<!!`?

For example, given the following code:

```
(go (let [response (<! (http/get "https://api.github.com/users"
                                 {:with-credentials? false
                                  :query-params {"since" 135}}))]
      (:status response)))
```

will return a channel but not `(:status response)`. How to make this go block return a `(:status response)`?

Answer (score 0):

`<!!` doesn't exist in javascript because the runtime does not support it. Javascript is single-threaded and `<!!` is a blocking operation. Blocking the main thread in a browser-based environment is a bad idea as it would simply freeze all javascript actions (and potentially freeze the whole page) until unblocked.

Instead, consider using [clojure.core.async/take!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core.async/take!) like so:

```clj
(take! channel (fn [value] (do-something-with value)))
```